# Windows 7 Unattended Setup Error

Tags: windows-7, setup, unattended

I'm trying to make an unattended installation of Windows 7 Homepremium x64 Sp1 on VM.
The AutoUnattend.xml (http://www7.zippyshare.com/v/j104hzpw/file.html) file was created and validated by Windows SIM.

[image]

[image]

I don't see any kind of problem in the [offlineServicing] section, so I don't know what to think. I removed some components and did some tests but with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Did some digging and found this, it seems that it has worked before. So give it a try.

- Removing ALL MSU patch packages from "Packages" section and re-add whatever necessary.
- I think it is something to do with version mismatch for IE (e.g. The image has IE9 while I have IE8 patches on Packages folder)...
  Removing ALL checked in OSes and re-add them back from freshly downloaded source ISOs (to avoid source file corruption)
- Don't mix both SP0 and SP1
  Starting MDT share from the scratch:
- The process of setting up entire share from scratch is not that hard as it sounds.
- You can drag and drop from the other share mostly but you need to be careful because you may "transfer" the root cause as-is too.
- It is recommended to create dummy Task Sequences matching with previous one and simply copy over old TS.xml.

I take no credit for this, in fact the answer was taken from [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d602ffaa-6117-418c-9927-d17909f69f50/windows-could-not-apply-unattend-settings-during-pass-offlineservicing?forum=mdt).